# How to render custom filenames in Helm charts?

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

A typical Helm chart structure is:

```
- templates
  - resources1.yaml
  - resources2.yaml
  - ...
Chart.yaml
values.yaml
```

Helm can render the content of resources files, but I also need to render filenames.

So having something similar to this:

```
- templates
  - resources1-$my-property.yaml
  - resources2-$my-property.yaml
  - ...
Chart.yaml
values.yaml
```

when I run something similiar to `helm template .  --set my-property=value1 --output-dir output`
I'd like to get this:

```
- outputs
  - chart
    - templates
      - resources1-value1.yaml
      - resources2-value1.yaml
      - ...
```

Could I get this functionality with Helm or should I need a different approach?

Comment: Usually if you `helm install` something, it gets sent to Kubernetes in a way that doesn't specifically include file names.  You could template file names inside a ConfigMap or some other YAML construct.  Can you say a little bit more about your higher-level use case here, where the file names matter?

Comment: Filenames matters because the use case is to create an PR with named files per a given variable. This PR is handled by another team who set this naming rules. So what I need is to render the template and produce the files. But not to install them. This is done by a CI/CD system owned by other team.

Comment: @EZequiel what are in these files? I find it odd for a helm chart to have a variable/dynamic set of files. The output of a Helm/sprig rendering can create a dynamic set of Kubernetes manifests. Helm command/chart itself cannot dynamically create helm template files. When you run `helm template` you are rendering the resulting Kubernetes manifests

Comment: If you want to run validation on the resulting Kubernetes manifests you could use [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/)